# Gitlab SSH Key Fingerprint mismatch

Tags: gitlab

I created a public and private SSH key of type ed25519 via the ssh-keygen command.

I have two Gitlab Installations and stored the public ssh key in Gitlab Profile. When I try to clone a repository Gitlab on server A it works correctly as expected but on server B i'm asked for the password.

Server A:

> ssh -T git@server-a
>
> Welcome to GitLab, @user!

Server B:

> ssh -T git@server-b
>
> The authenticity of host 'server-b' can't be established.
> ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:K0vuxkNHqP9Qp3j7rkQMppgCQtFaZjXQTwGp4ccIsrY.

Server A: host key algorith ssh-ed25519 is used

> ssh -Tvvv git@server-a

```
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:ebtDdgkJ5OBH1lBxhPA59xPMSVRcZMPOxe3tnYvPGE0
```

The strange thing is that on server B the ecdsa algorithm is used instead of ed25519:

```
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:K0vuxkNHqP9Qp3j7rkQMppgCQtFaZjXQTwGp4ccIsrY
```

On my local PC:

> ssh-keygen -lf .ssh/id_ed25519.pub
>
> 256 SHA256:eFKEYbjf8Frjp96UzXwWMfOJHXTe/TEEwTkneKkN/8Y  (ED25519)

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out the cause:
On server A with RHEL 8 FIPS is disabled but on server B FIPS was enabled and with enabled FIPS ED25519 SSH keys are not supported.

So I had to disable FIPS on server B and the ssh connection with ED25519 key worked as expected.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/367429